# git: merge only a selection of files

Tags: git, version-control

We are working on an Embedded project.
Currently, we have a working hardware with controller A.
Later, the final product will have a new hardware with controller B.
I'm currently implementing the business logic on branch 1, using our old hardware with controller A.
My collegues are porting the software for controller B on branch 2. They are adapting all the low level stuff, device drivers, HAL and stuff.

Soon we will have to merge branch 1 into branch 2.

However, we will only want to merge a small portion of the files.
It's senseless to try to merge device drivers. On controller B, we will have completely different device drivers and HALs.
Also, it makes no sense to merge board-dependant configuration files.

But when I run "git merge 1" on branch 2 I will get a lot of merge conflicts because git will try to merge every file.
I need some way of picking a set of file which I want to merge.

My solution now is to not use the "git merge" feature.
Instead I create two local repositories, one on branch 1 and one on branch 2.
Then I can use some random difftool and merge a selection of files by hand.
However, with this solution git will not know that I did a merge.
Also, the branch tree view will not reflect my "merge".

So, is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why can't you checkout both branches, copy the files you want into branch B, overwrite the files there, commit. Surely you must know which files you are working with.

Comment: I can, but this "merge" would not be reflected in git's visual tree view. From a git-point-of-view, this would not be a merge but a usual commit.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. Just close down a branch and say that it is no longer maintained. The "visual appeal of the revision tree" is irrelevant.

Comment: @lugge86 Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

You use the cherry-pick command to get individual commits from one branch.

If the change(s) you want are not in individual commits, then use the method shown here to split the commit into individual commits. Roughly speaking, you use git rebase -i to get the original commit to edit, then git reset HEAD^ to selectively revert changes, then git commit to commit that bit as a new commit in the history.

There is another nice method here in Red Hat Magazine, where they use git add --patch or possibly git add --interactive which allows you to add just parts of a hunk, if you want to split different changes to an individual file (search in that page for "split").

Having split the changes, you can now cherry-pick just the ones you want.